# Select statement for xdoc query 

Tags: c#, xml, linq, web-services, rest

I am trying to add a sub category to Messages in my xml statement Is there a way I can do this `GroupMessages -> Message -> GroupMessage` :

```
        var groups = xDoc.Descendants("Group")
            .Select(n => new
            {
                GroupName = n.Element("GroupName").Value,
                GroupHeader = n.Element("GroupHeader").Value,
                TimeCreated = DateTime.Parse(n.Element("TimeAdded").Value),
                Tags = n.Element("Tags").Value, 
                Messages = n.Element("GroupMessages").Value
                //line above
            })
            .ToList();
        dataGrid2.ItemsSource = groups;
```

In my method GroupMessages contains both MessageID and GroupMessage and it is listing both in my datagrid within the one container. So I tried this but it lists nothing:

```
 Messages = n.Descendants("GroupMessages").Select(nd => nd.Element("GroupMessage").Value)
```

My XML looks like this:

```
<Group>
<TimeAdded>2012-04-27T10:23:50.7153613+01:00</TimeAdded>
<GroupName>Group</GroupName>
<GroupHeader>Header</GroupHeader>
<GroupMessages>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<GroupMessage>Message</GroupMessage>
<MessageGroup/>
</Message>
</GroupMessages>
</Group>
```

I have also tried:

```
Messages = n.Descendants("GroupMessages").Select(nd => nd.Descendants("Message").Select(nde => nde.Element("GroupMessage").Value))
```

To no avail?

Update:

```
    private void ListGroups_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string uriGroup = "http://localhost:8000/Service/Group";
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uriGroup);
        var groups = xDoc.Descendants("Group")
                    .Select(n => new
        {
            GroupName = n.Element("GroupName").Value,
            GroupHeader = n.Element("GroupHeader").Value,
            TimeCreated = n.Element("TimeAdded").Value,
            Tags = n.Element("Tags").Value,
            Messages = n.Element("GroupMessages").Descendants("Message").Select(nd => new
            {
                //Id = nd.Element("MessageID").Value,
                Message = nd.Element("GroupMessage").Value
            }).FirstOrDefault()
        })
        .ToList();
        dataGrid2.ItemsSource = groups;
    }
```

Unfortunatley this method shows "Collection" inside the cell in the datagrid. If I try ToArray it will show an array message inside the cell. Is there a way to actually display the GroupMessage? Not sure how you set the child elements of a datagrid?

Comment: Can you have more than one `Message` in `GroupMessages`?

Comment: yes you can, hence the ID (from some of my previous questions you have seen)

Comment: So do you want to return more than one message? Or the first one? Or something else...? If more than one, how do you plan on displaying more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the most basic level, you can do this to get a **single message (the first one)**:

```
var groups = from grp in xDoc.Descendants("Group")
             select new { 
                GroupName = grp.Element("GroupName").Value,
                GroupHeader = grp.Element("GroupHeader").Value,
                TimeCreated = DateTime.Parse(grp.Element("TimeAdded").Value),
                Message = grp.Element("GroupMessages").Element("Message").Element("GroupMessage").Value
             };
```

However, I assume that you want `Messages` to be a list of messages with both ID and Message. In that case, consider this:

```
var groups = from grp in xDoc.Descendants("Group")
             select new { 
                GroupName = grp.Element("GroupName").Value,
                GroupHeader = grp.Element("GroupHeader").Value,
                TimeCreated = DateTime.Parse(grp.Element("TimeAdded").Value),
                Messages = grp.Element("GroupMessages")
                             .Descendants("Message")
                             .Select(msg => new { 
                                 Id = msg.Element("MessageID").Value, 
                                 Message = msg.Element("GroupMessage").Value
                             }).ToList()
             };
```

However, I **strongly stress** that all this usage of anonymous classes is just going to cause confusion. If you have a class for `Group` and `Message` then use those.

Note that the problem you're having is you're ignoring the XML structure and selecting random elements. To get the value out of a single element, you're going to need to select exactly that element, and ask for `.Value`. Selecting it's parent, or it's parent's parent (as you did) is not enough.

Comment: Yamen this doesnt display anything.

Comment: see my update which is working partially but it shows "Collection" inside the Message Cell. How can I show both ID and the Message?

Comment: Which message? You have more than one message, hence it returned a collection (a list) of messages. If you want just (say) the first message for each group you need to say so. You're not doing yourself any real favours with these questions.

Comment: At the time I only had one message but message also has messageID so it is returned to the one cell as a collection. Is there a way to display child elements in the datagrid? Note I have also tryed ommited the messageID in the hope it would return just one element in the Message value. It didnt.

Comment: P.s if I use FirstOrDefault it works but for some reason the message has {Message = some random message} around it inside the cell?

Comment: You have some options: 1) Use my first bit of code and it will return just the message (note I think I used the parameter name `Message` instead of `Messages`). 2) You can return multiple messages if you want to concatenate them or something into say a comma delimited list. Try option 1) first and let us know if it works.

Comment: Ah I figured it out I used your method with mine `var groups = xDoc.Descendants("Group")
                        .Select(n => new
                         {` then I used your method and now only the message appears with no funny formating. Great! +1 But now to sort out some type of format for multiple messages.

Comment: Please accept this question then :-) (Yes I used the query format rather `.Select` etc so there may have been a problem transposing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var groups = xDoc.Elements("Group")
            .Select(n => new
            {
                GroupName = n.Get("GroupName", string.Empty),
                GroupHeader = n.Get("GroupHeader", string.Empty),
                TimeCreated = n.Get("TimeAdded", DateTime.MinValue),
                Tags = n.Get("Tags", string.Empty),
                Messages = n.GetEnumerable("GroupMessages/Message", m => new
                {
                    Id = m.Get("MessageID", 0),
                    Message = m.Get("GroupMessage", string.Empty),
                    Group = m.Get("MessageGroup", string.Empty)
                }).ToArray()
            })
            .ToList();
```

I used the extension methods from here: http://searisen.com/xmllib/extensions.wiki

Get will handle null cases like your `Tags` node that doesn't exist in your xml, as well as the empty tag `MessageGroup`.  You should use `Elements()` if the node you want is the child of the node you are referencing and not any descendant by that name.

I copied your xml into a root node to test it.  It works on this xml:

```
<root>
  <Group>
    <TimeAdded>2012-04-27T10:23:50.7153613+01:00</TimeAdded>
    <GroupName>Group</GroupName>
    <GroupHeader>Header</GroupHeader>
    <GroupMessages>
      <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <GroupMessage>Message</GroupMessage>
        <MessageGroup/>
      </Message>
    </GroupMessages>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <TimeAdded>2012-04-27T10:23:50.7153613+01:00</TimeAdded>
    <GroupName>Group</GroupName>
    <GroupHeader>Header</GroupHeader>
    <GroupMessages>
      <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <GroupMessage>Message</GroupMessage>
        <MessageGroup/>
      </Message>
    </GroupMessages>
  </Group>
</root>
```

Comment: Sorry but I really dont want to use the extension you mention. Or any extensions.