# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, rest, entity-relationship

This is a follow up question from here: [linq issue with creating relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345489/linq-issue-with-creating-relationships) in regards  to the answer I recieved. Im not sure what has happend but I get an error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

And this is where the exception happens:

```
    string uriGroup = "http://localhost:8000/Service/Group";
    private void ListGroups_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uriGroup); // this line
        var groups = xDoc.Descendants("Group")
            .Select(n => new
            {
                GroupName = n.Element("GroupName").Value,
                GroupHeader = n.Element("GroupHeader").Value,
                TimeCreated = DateTime.Parse(n.Element("TimeAdded").Value),
                Tags = n.Element("Tags").Value, 
                Messages = n.Element("GroupMessages").Value
            })
            .ToList();

        dataGrid2.ItemsSource = groups;
    }
```

Comment: [Enabled tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)? No? Do it and you'll see detailed error :)

Comment: This is hosted in a console app, so dont think this will work.

Comment: If you hit the URL uriGroup via a browser, what do you see?

Comment: @JungleBoogie, Reniuz is right. WCF Tracing can be enabled even if you are self-hosting.  Modify your app.config instead of your web.config

Comment: There is no app.config or web.config.

Comment: If your self-hosted app is called "foo", its config file will be "foo.exe.config"

Comment: project -> add -> new item... -> application configuration file

Comment: Can you show us where `uriGroup` is defined? I can see `string uriGroup = ...` in the `CreateGroup_Click` definition but nothing in `ListGroups_Click`.

Comment: @yamen Hi bud, its the same string. I have updated my code to reflect this.

Comment: Which operation does `Service/Group` correspond to? And are all your initial `POST` messages not returning any errors (just confirm status is OK)?

Comment: We also really need to see what error the server is throwing. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933956/wcf-tracing-how-i-can-get-the-exact-reason-for-closing-connection

Comment: Service/Group is a GET request that returns a list of Groups. And the posts return status OK only the GET requests for list groups/messages I get that error.

Comment: Here is another question you might want to look at that might help understand the xml layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341145/select-statement-for-xdoc-query

Comment: I commented but it seems to have disappeared. 1) We need to see the code for 'Service/Group' not just hear what it does 2) You need to enable tracing as requested multiple times from multiple people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are returning a `List` of objects, it is possible that you have exceeded the [MaxItemsInObjectGraph](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c85f3ed2-0b55-4375-af79-5926b6cc527c/).  You can increase the value by modifying your web.config (or app.config):

```
<behaviors>
    <behavior>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600" />
    </behavior>
</behaviors>
```

You may also want to consider looking at the usual suspects:

- `<readerquota>` values
- MaxReceivedMessageSize
- MaxBufferSize
- MaxBufferPoolSize

You should enable [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) as it will contain more detailed errors. Yes, this works even for self-hosted apps.

Comment: @Downvoter, I would really appreciate constructive criticism on my answer so that I may provide better quality responses in the future. Please kindly share your thoughts and opinions.